# I mounted Android on Ubuntu. Can I create subdirectories using mtpfs?

Tags: linux, mtp

I use Android 4.0 and followed a [tutorial](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/12/how-to-connect-your-android-ice-cream-sandwich-phone-to-ubuntu-for-file-access) to mount my tablet on Ubuntu using mtpfs when the device is connected via cable.

It works almost perfectly. I can copy files and even whole directories to the device through Nautilus. However, when a directory contains subdirectories I get an error when a subdirectory is being copied ("Error creating directory: No such file or directory"). Other files are copied fine. In the same way, I can't create subdirectories in a directory directly via Nautilus.

What causes this? Is this expected? Any workaround?

Comment: What device are you using?

Comment: Oh man, it's a cheap tablet from a manufacturer called "Evertek". :P The model name is Genesis GT-7240. It's a pretty sweet model for $100 bucks btw. Heh. I connect it to the desktop using a Micro-USB. Site: http://everteksa.com/prod_gt7240_pt.php